# iOS / Xcode 4: View won't load

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xcode4

This is really frustrating as I've tinkered with previous versions of Xcode and have done this before but playing around with a new app now, it's not working for some reason.

I have the app open to a UITableView and want it to load to a detail UIView once I select a cell. However, when I choose a cell in the iPhone simulator, it just highlights the cell blue and doesn't load the view.

Here is the code I'm using the the RootViewController:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
WorkoutViewController *workoutViewController;
workoutViewController = [[WorkoutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WorkoutViewController" bundle:nil];
workoutViewController.workoutName = [workouts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:workoutViewController animated:YES];
[workoutViewController release];
workoutViewController = nil;
```

I have the view linked to the File Owner in the WorkoutViewController.xib file. When I put in a breakpoint at @implementation WorkoutViewController, it does get to that breakpoint but it goes to the @synthesize line and then jumps right back out to [self.navigationController ...etc]; and never returns back to the WorkoutViewController.m file.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in what you are doing. Maybe we need to see a bit more code. The didSelectRowAtIndexPath is being fired (as the breakpoint indicates) and the reason it goes to @synthesize is i'm assuming you have workoutName as a property in the workoutViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you didn't set the ViewController to be the TableView's delegate. To check, open your ViewController xib-file and rightclick `FilesOwner`. Under `Referencing Outlet` you would usually have both `delegate` and `data` source" connected to your `TableView`. If that is not the case, drag `New Referencing Outlet` to your TableView.

If I'm wrong and they are all connected, you might want put a breakpoint at the beginning of your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. Does the debugger stop there, once you select a row?

It might also be worth mentioning that a breakpoint at `@implementation` usually doesn't make much sense, you would rather want to place it in a method like init. Also, even though you are using Xcode 4 now, this is unlikely to be the cause of your problem, it looks more like an implementation issue.

Hope this helps, if you need further help just let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Doh! Problem resolved. I had forgotten to actually put the RootViewController into a navigation controller on the MainWindow.xib. Appreciate the responses.